# Does this tricky series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_2 \frac{\cos(\log{n})}{n\log{n}}$$

The naive attempt is to use dirichlet's test to falsely claim that $\cos(\log{n})$ has bounded partial sums, but I don't think it works.

I am also trying a difference of sum and integral type of strategy but am not sure where to go from it.

Finally, as A.S pointed out below in the comments, the integral test does not apply, since cos(logn) does not behave monotonically...

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: The integral  $\int_2^\infty \frac{cos(log(x))}{x log(x)} dx$ is convergent, just use the substitution $u = log(x)$.

Comment: @mlu That's a satisfactory answer to the question, so why don't you post it as an answer and not a comment?

Comment: @Gregory Because intergral test doesn't apply to unmonotonic sequences.

Comment: There are few details to work out, and its very late :), the integral approximation will probably work but the approximation errors must be checked carefully.

Comment: Right, @A.S., I should have added that.  I will edit now...

Comment: @A.S. I assumed it was absolutely convergent, is that not the case?

Comment: not absolutely convergent, but the log varies slowly so the cos will create cancellation.

Comment: yeah but isn't it $\int\frac{cos(u)}{u}du$ after the substitution?  No more log...

Comment: yeah, and its convergent

Comment: Just break up the range into $\log n\in[\pi/2+k\pi,\pi/2+(k+1)\pi)$. On each piece cos is of the same sign (and bounded) and sum of 1/denom over the range goes down to zero - so by alternating series test this converges. You wouldn't have convergence if there was no $\log$ in the denominator, for example.

Comment: @A.S. How do you know those cosines in the numerator don't accumulate because the number of terms in that range increases with $k$ doesn't it?

Comment: Hi @A.S. how does that work?  Are we re-indexing?  Or decomposing the sum?  Thanks,

Comment: @User001 He's suggesting grouping all consecutive terms with the same sign.  It's a good idea but I think the argument is incomplete, it's not clear to me that the terms once grouped do go to zero, it's not enough that cosine is bounded because the number of consecutive terms with the same sign goes to infinity (I think).

Comment: No reindexing. Just decomposing the sum into pos/neg terms lumped together which signify "maximal deviations". @Gregory are you  missing the second part of the argument the sum of 1/denom over the $k$-th range goes down as $\Theta(1/k)$?

Comment: @A.S. Yes I am missing that, I don't see why the sum over the range goes to zero.  What exactly do you mean by $\Theta(1/k)$?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Since the number of consecutive terms with the same sign goes to infinity and $|\cos(n)|\leq1$, all we know is that the sum of consecutive positive terms is less than $\sum\frac{1}{n\log n}$ over that range, but the sum $\frac1{n\log n}$ diverges so those partial sums do not go to zero.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are missing the fact that we are summing over a *limited* range $[a,b]$ only and the sum over the range behaves as $\log\log b-\log\log a$.

Comment: @A.S. Yes but $b-a\rightarrow\infty$ no?

Comment: @Gregory So want? The ratio of logs of $a_k$ and $b_k$ is $1+\Theta(1/k)$.

Comment: @A.S.  If the sum over the range behaves like $\log\log b - \log\log a$ and $b-a$ goes to infinity as $k$ goes to infinity, then the sum over the range goes to infinity, no?  I'm sorry if I'm being dense here but this argument is really not clear to me.  I'm perfectly happy to admit I'm being stupid, but I'll need a rigorous detailed argument to follow.  Again I don't know what $\Theta(1/k)$ means.

Comment: No. For example, $\log{2k}-\log{k}=\log 2<\infty$ even though $2k-k\to\infty$. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) for big $\Theta$ notation.

Comment: @A.S. Why didn't you say it was big O, I've never seen that notated with a theta that's all, and I don't see that on that page either.  Anyway, as I said, I wasn't convinced your proof was wrong, just that it was incomplete.  You have gone some of the way to completing it in the additional comments.

Comment: @Greg Had you searched wikipedia's page for "theta", you would have found both the definition and details of its use. It's not seen that often in math, but is used all the time in analysis of algorithms. Why wouldn't you want to convene more info (2-sided bound) when you can do it "for free"?

Comment: @A.S. I did actually, but all I found was the theta function.

Comment: Hi Professor Grant, the idea by mlu (please see below) works - I have verified this.  Thanks for generating some interesting discussion for this problem statement @gregorygrant,

Comment: Thanks for your time @A.S.

Comment: @User001 Thank you it's very nice of you to post these thank yous, you are a gentleman (or woman, ambiguous user name) and a scholar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First examine the corresponding integral:

$$\int_2^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\log(x))}{x \log(x)}dx = \int_{log(2)}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(u)}{u} du = \left[ \frac{\sin(u)}{u} \right]_{log(2)}^{\infty} + \int_{log(2)}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(u)}{u^2}du $$ this is convergent.

Next we look at the derivative of the function 
$$\begin{align}f(x) &= \frac{\cos(\log(x))}{x \log(x)} \\
f'(x) &= \frac{-1/x \cdot\sin(\log(x))\cdot x \log(x) + \cos(\log(x))(\log(x)+1)}{(x \log(x))^2}\\
 |f'(x)| &< \frac{2}{x^2}\end{align}$$ so we can compare the terms of sum and the integral over intervals of length 1:
$$\begin{align} \left| \frac{\cos(\log(k))}{k \log(k)} - \int_k^{k+1} \frac{\cos(\log(x))}{x \log(x)} dx \right| &\leq \int_k^{k+1} | f(k) - f(x) | dx \\ &\leq \max_{k<x<k+1} | f'(x) | < \frac{2}{k^2} \end{align}$$

Since the integral and the sum of the differences both are convergent, the original series is convergent.

Comment: I thought we agreed the integral test does not apply here.

Comment: the approximations in the test must be shown to be convergent, thats why its still incomplete

Comment: I think that some text explaining why the things you mention are relevant would be a good addition.

Comment: Hi @mlu, your last inequality is where I've been stuck at for awhile.  How do you get the upper bound though?  That is your bound for the derivative, but we do not have a derivative.  Unless you are looking at finite-differencing?  Thanks,

Comment: difference $f(x) - f(k) =  (x-k)f'(\xi)$

Comment: Ooh I see @mlu ... hmm ...

Comment: I hope its getting clearer

Comment: Conditionally convergent, yes.

Comment: yes , I didnt look clearly, my bad, but its not the same logic.

Comment: The important part is that we look at cos in widely spaced points log(k) to make the derivative decrease like $1/x^2$. The derivative of $\cos(x)/x$ only decreases like $1/x$

Comment: Hi @mlu, I was able to work out all the details and agree with your work.  So, the convergence of the difference forces the convergence of the sum?  (We already know the second term in the difference, namely, the integral, converges.)  Or is there more to say, in order to conclude?  Thanks so much,

Comment: Very pretty and very timely application of the mean value theorem, BTW - that was the key point, I thought, @mlu - thanks so much,